# Unable to pull non-US BigQuery datasets via Simba ODBC Excel driver for Mac

Tags: excel, macos, google-bigquery, odbc

I have installed the ODBC driver manager and the Simba ODBC driver for BigQuery (v2.4.1.1009 from the [Google Cloud docs](http://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers)) onto my Mac, and successfully set up authorisation and the .ini configuration file to the point that I am able to see all my tables in the Get Data from Database view in Excel. However, when I try to query any dataset that isn't in the US, I get the following error:

> "[Simba][BigQuery] (31750) Dataset is not found. Not found: Dataset
> project-name:dataset-name was not found in location US.

All my datasets are in the EU, but I created a test dataset in the US in the same project and was able to successfully query a test table there using the connection, so I'm confident that it's not an authorisation issue.

Having looked thoroughly in the [documentation](https://storage.googleapis.com/simba-bq-release/odbc/Simba%20Google%20BigQuery%20ODBC%20Connector%20Install%20and%20Configuration%20Guide.pdf) for the driver, I couldn't find any settings to add to the .ini file to specify a processing location or region, nor did I find a way to explicitly specify a dataset location in BigQuery SQL. The documentation does make mention of a "QueryProperties" setting, which apparently supports the same properties of the connectionProperties of the [JobConfigurationQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#JobConfigurationQuery) of the "Job" type in the BigQuery API, however this is listed as [only supporting the time_zone property](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/ConnectionProperty).

I've been able to access these datasets regularly before via the equivalent ODBC driver for Windows, also from Simba, but I'm not sure if this a limitation specific to the Mac version, or if I'm missing a setting somewhere? It was a while ago, but I'm pretty sure I didn't have to specify a region at any point when using the Windows version.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you please confirm which version of Simba ODBC driver you are using?

Comment: Hey @PrajnaRaiT, I sourced the dmg from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/odbc-jdbc-drivers, which is  version 2.4.1.1009. Strangely, that seems to be later than the "current" 2.3.3 version that shows on the Magnitude website. Updated my original question.

Comment: Hi @Iblnd, Specifying location from a connection string is not supported in the ODBC driver. This limitation comes from Google's API that we are using. Currently, the supported connection property is [time_zone](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/ConnectionProperty), whose value represents the default timezone used to run the query.

Comment: As a workaround can you try to create a dataset in the cloud project for a large result set in the same region that the source table is located, and specify it for the "LargeResultsDataSetId" [connection property](https://simba.wpengine.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/mac/content/odbc/bq/options/ui/largeresultsdatasetid.htm).

Comment: @lblnd, can you please share how you "successfully set up authorisation and the .ini configuration file"?